# Seaside - How do I install Scriptaculous on a clean Seaside install (via Configuration Browser) on Pharo?

Tags: pharo, seaside

I used the method described [here](http://forum.world.st/Seaside-on-Pharo-3-0-tp4726765p4727131.html) to install Seaside3 on Pharo. All is well, but Scriptaculous doesn't come preinstalled. How do I get it?

Seaside3 :

1: Go to the configuration manager

2: Select the Seaside 3 configuration. Click on Install.

3: Wait while it loads. Takes a couple of minutes on an i7 and a decent network link.

4: Open a Workspace and start a ZincServerAdaptor on the port you like (here 8080):
ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 8080. (then CMD+d for Do It)

7: Access Seaside from your browser.

8: Install Scriptaculous, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Johan B's input:**

http://forum.world.st/Seaside-How-do-I-install-Scriptaculous-on-a-clean-Seaside-install-via-Configuration-Browser-on-Pharo-td4802930.html

Pharo’s Configuration browser loads the default group of the Metacello configuration, which unfortunately was set to ‘Core’ for Seaside 3.1. 
So, you will need to load additional groups programmatically:

```
(ConfigurationOfSeaside3 project version: #stable) load: #('Scriptaculous' 'JSON')
```

If you want to get the list of possible groups to load, inspect:

```
(ConfigurationOfSeaside3 project version: #stable) groups
```

Install from scratch with:

```
(ConfigurationOfSeaside3 project version: #stable) load: #('default' 'Scriptaculous' 'JSON')
```

This is something we fixed for Seaside 3.2, where the default will load everything to help newcomers. 
We prefer not to change the existing 3.1 configuration versions to not break existing uses, but it’s fixed in the upcoming version.

Btw, Scriptaculous is really outdated. You will prefer to use jQuery and jQuery-UI (or any other JS framework…)

**My findings on the subject:**

Well, finally figured it out.

The packages needed for Scriptaculous to work are listed in the book here:
http://book.seaside.st/book/web-20/scriptaculous/frameworks/installation

Then you need to find a repository to get them from, after a little poking around here:
http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/

I chose the Seaside31 repository, which is what I apparently managed to install a few hours ago.

http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main

Then I had to Do-It a couple of times on (maybe there is a faster way to do this):

```
Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'Javascript-Core';
    load.

Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'Prototype-Core';
    load.

Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'Scriptaculous-Core';
    load.

Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'Scriptaculous-Components';
    load.
```

For those looking to install jQuery into Seaside can use these:

```
Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'Javascript-Core';
    load.  

Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'JQuery-Core';
    load.

Gofer new
    url:'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/Seaside31/main';
    package: 'JQuery-UI'; "notice that there is no -Core on this one, I don't know why"
    load.
```

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to load a full fledged configuration in Pharo 4.0 (after having loaded Seaside from the configuration browser):

```
| config groups |

config := (ConfigurationOfSeaside3 project version: #release3).

"Inspect this in case you want to see what's available"
groups := config groups.

"Load the usual suspects"
config load: #('OneClick' 'Javascript' 'Javascript Tests' 'JQuery' 'JQuery Tests' 'JQueryUI' 'JQueryUI Tests' 'JQueryUI Examples' 'REST' 'REST Tests' 'JSON' 'JSON Tests').
```

An additional interesting configuration to load is Bootstrap.
Check the configuration browser.